# gtk_main update GUI

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk

I'm applying GUI using GTK libraries to my program. In short, I compute a variable for every time i have an input, and then the input is shown in a text using gtk_text_buffer. The problem is that whenever I receive the input (everything is in a while loop, but it's almost 200 lines of code, so I won't post it), I can see from both command line and GUI that, the input doesn't update unless I close the window, then it will open again and show the updated result. After some experimentation I found out that the problem is gtk_main. If i call it, I have that issue. If i don't the program works fine, but won't show the GUI. If I use a loop

```
while (gtk_events_pending())
    {
       gtk_main_iteration();
       gtk_main();  
    }
```

The input is updated all the time, but for each update opens a new window (showing the right result, but it opens infinite for each input). Has anyone got a solution how to keep updating the GUI without have to close the window every time?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call `gtk_main();` in a loop as it is runs that loop by itself:

```
while (not_exit)
{
  gtk_main_iteration();
}
```

Other than that it is not clear why do you need such construct at all, `gtk_main();` is enough.

Comment: gtk_main, should be enough according to documentation. But it doesn't loop unless I close the window. Basically it will start the loop again only if I close the window (then it will automatically start again by it self)